# Define HTML check boxes from database values

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

I have project with HTML PHP and SQL database. I designed HTML input form to collect data from user and put drop down menu using PHP. It collected data from SQL database using query and those data used to drop down list and user can select those data. I have using following codes in PHP section.

```
$query2 = "SELECT Name FROM class ORDER BY Name";   
$results2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results2))
{
    $Classes .= "<option value=\"{$result['Name']}\">{$result['Name']}</option>";
}
```

In my database there are several classes as Class_A, Class_B, Class_C and etc. (Admin can create new class or delete available class. Then when user select classes, showing classes can be different according to Admin's settings.)

In HTML form section I used following code to display Class names.

```
<p>
    <label for=" ">Classes Are</label><br>
    <select name="Classes[]" size="3" multiple >
    <?php echo $Classes ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

I tried to use this process through Check boxes (replace Drop down list from Check boxes) But I cant fix that. So, If someone can give proper way to do this it is highly appreciate.

Comment: What was the problem with using `checkboxes` that stopped you progressing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need to use `checkboxes`? The `name` assigned to the HTML input element uses an `array` type syntax with the name of from the db supplied

```
$sql = "select `name` from `class` order by `name`";   
$res = $connection->query( $sql );
while( $rs = res->fetch_object() ) {
    $classes=sprintf(
        '<label>%1$s: 
            <input type="checkbox" value="%1$s" name="Classes[%1$s]" />
        </label>',
        $rs->name
    );
}
```

Then, to process the form submission once the user has selected one or more checkboxes you could do:

```
foreach( $_POST['Classes'] as $index => $value ){
    // do things...
}
```

You likely do not even need to add the name so perhaps simply `Classes[]` as the input name would suffice. Please clarify the issue you had when trying to use `checkboxes` rather than `select` menus.